# General error: 1 cannot rollback - no transaction is active cakephp?

Tags: sqlite, cakephp-3.0

I was getting the error in cakephp 3.0. Everything was all right there was no error in code. I have spend at least 30-40 minutes to figure it out.So i am posting it here hope it can save other times. Below are the answers please follow the steps and it will fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Please follow the steps to fix this bugs in cakephp 3.0

1) Check the **tmp**  directory of your cakephp application 
2) There is a file name with **debug_kit.sqlite** delete it.
3) Off the debug mode from the config files i.e **'debug' => false,** 
4) Now check the application on browser the error will not no more.

This solution work for me :)